# Retrieving value out of Associative array c#

Tags: c#, lisp

I'm stucked on my next problem.

I read a line from a textfile containing like:

```
(("ITEM" "05") ("NUMBER" "1") ("DESCRIPTION" "*RECHTE INSTEEKKOP. 1/4\"-8MM") ("ARTICLENUMBER" "S110010000104"))
```

In Lisp this is a List and for retrieving the value of eg `ITEM` in Lisp:

```
(cadr (assoc "ITEM" str))
```

This gives `05`

How can I achieve this simply in C#?

Comment: There is no *"simply"*, this is not a naively *serializable* file in *.net*. Firstly you will need to *read* the file, *parse* the file into a *dictionary*, then return the *value* you want by *key*

Comment: Answers for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051254/parsing-lisp-s-expressions-with-known-schema-in-c-sharp) should help. And this [article](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/S-Expressions#C.23).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Regex to parse the value and then fetch the result. For example,

```
var valueCollection = Regex.Matches(datastring,@"\(""(?<Key>.+?(?=""))""\s+""(?<Value>.+?(?=""))""\)")
                                 .Cast<Match>()
                                .Select(x=>new {Key = x.Groups["Key"].Value,Value = x.Groups["Value"].Value,});
```

This would provide you with collection as the following

[image]

You could now fetch the Value where Key is equal to "ITEM" using Linq.

```
var itemValue = valueCollection.First(x=>x.Key=="ITEM").Value;
```

Alternatively, you could convert the string to a Dictionary as

```
var valueCollection = Regex.Matches(datastring,@"\(""(?<Key>.+?(?=""))""\s+""(?<Value>.+?(?=""))""\)")
                                 .Cast<Match>()
                                 .ToDictionary(x=>x.Groups["Key"].Value,y=>y.Groups["Value"].Value);
```

You could now parse the required `ITEM` value as

```
var itemValue = valueCollection["ITEM"];
```

**Update Based on comment**

In case you expect empty values, you could use the following regex pattern.

```
@"\(""(?<Key>.+?(?=""))""\s+""(?<Value>.*?(?=""))""\)"
```

Comment: Nice work, though what if  the list has an escaped `)` ?

Comment: @Marco Glad it helped. Kindly mark it as Answer/Helpful if it helped in resolving your issue

Comment: I got an error when value is "".
In next line "DIMENSIONS" is empty.

    *(("ITEM" "01") ("NUMBER" "4") ("DESCRIPTION" "LUIK TEMA Ø 450") ("DIMENSIONS" "") ("REMARKS" "VOLGENS S000001-0004") ("ABS" "S") ("CADID" "32A96") ("ARTICLENUMBER" "S000001-0004") ("ZAAGCODE" "") ("Snijden" ""))*

Comment: @Anu Thanks, works fine! I try to understand regex.matches but no change. So I give up and just copy paste it in my code and it works. I will try again to understand later.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is using `Split` function

```
string values = "((\"ITEM\" \"05\") (\"NUMBER\" \"1\") (\"DESCRIPTION\" \" * RECHTE INSTEEKKOP. 1 / 4\" - 8MM\") (\"ARTICLENUMBER\" \"S110010000104\"))";

var keyValuePairs = values.Split(new[] { "(", ")", " (", ") " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Select(s => s.Split(new[] { ' ' }, 2))
                    .ToDictionary(x => x[0].ToString(), x => x[1].ToString());
```

Output

[image]